# Install EAR into WebSphere 8.5 Cluster without affecting the application availability

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have created 1 dynamic cluster with 2 WAS in it. I am deploying my application EAR on cluster using Ant scripts. In order to install the new application, I have to stop the already running application, uninstall the application, install the new application, then start the application. This is affecting the availability of my application. Is there any way through which I can achieve the application availability while deploying the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [Deploying and managing application editions with Intelligent Management](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twve_appedtop.html?lang=en)

> The application edition manager controls interruption-free production
>   application deployments. Interruption-free deployment prevents loss of
>   service when you install an application update in your environment.

It is a bit too wide subject to discuss here, so read detailed concepts on that page and subpages.

Comment: where can I specify the Application Edition if I am installing EAR using ANT?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari - Check this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rwve_adtaskapped.html?lang=en) it is installation using `wsadmin`, you can probably call wsadmin from your ant script or switch to wsadmin scripts.

Comment: I passed edition as option in "wsInstallApp" target. e.g options="-edition 1.0". It worked like a charm.