# Options supported by "wsInstallApp" ant target in WAS 8.5.5 ND

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

"wsInstallApp" ant target has the property named "options". What are the options supported by this target? I can not find ant information on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a direct answer, but combined from information on the following pages:

- [wsInstallApp javadoc](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/ant/tasks/InstallApplication.html?lang=en) - says:

> This task is a wrapper for the AdminApp.install() command of the
>   wsadmin tool. Refer to the wsadmin documentation for information on
>   the valid options available during application installation.

- [AdminApp.install options list](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html?lang=en)
  I'm not attaching all the options here as the list is very long.

PS. Unfortunately it lacks `edition` option you needed in the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682882/install-ear-into-websphere-8-5-cluster-without-affecting-the-application-availab/29683331?noredirect=1#comment47508919_29683331). :)

Comment: I passed edition as option in "wsInstallApp" target. e.g options="-edition 1.0". It worked for me. It installed the EAR with application edition 1.0.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari Yes I've seen, thanks for sharing that.